# Controller as syntax does not change controller's variable value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried to implement for first time the controller as syntax and I face a problem where my function doesn't change the controller variable which I pass from the template. Instead it understands the parameter as a local variable. This wouldn't happen if I use $scope.

Here's my controller.

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('baseCtrl', baseCtrl);

  function baseCtrl() {

  base = this;
  base.myVar = 'string_1';
  base.myFunction = myFunction;

  function myFunction(value) {
    value = 'string_2"';
  }
}
```

Here's my template.

```
<div ng-controller="baseCtrl as base">
  <button ng-click="base.myFunction(base.myVar)">Button</button>
</div>
```

After click base.myVar should change from "string_1" to "string_2" but this doesn't happen.

Does somebody know how I could figure it out ?

Comment: *"This wouldn't happen if I use $scope"* .. why not, what would difference be? Your function is still only changing a local variable

Comment: I think base might be a keyword or something in JavaScript; maybe that has to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

it can be done like this , do some changes in your code

```js
angular
    .module('app',[])
    .controller('baseCtrl',function(){

   var base = this;
   base.myVar = 'string_1';
  base.myFunction = myFunction;
  
  
  function myFunction(value) {
    value = 'string_2"';
    base.myVar = value
   alert(value);
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="baseCtrl as base">
  <input type="text" ng-model="base.myVar"/>
  <button ng-click="base.myFunction(base.myVar)">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: What I need is not to declare base.myVar in the function, but the value to be indexing at base.myVar or any other variable I pass.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assign

```
base.myVar = 'string"';
```

in myFunction and define module app like this:-

```
angular.module('app',[]);
```

This is the modified code that will work.

```
angular
.module('app', [])
.controller('baseCtrl', baseCtrl);

function baseCtrl() {
    var base = this;
    base.myVar = 'string_1';
    base.myFunction = myFunction;
    function myFunction(value) {
        base.myVar = 'string_2"';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
base.myVar = "string2"
```

That will fix it

Comment: I need to use this function globally...so everytime I pass a parameter I need to change the relative controller variable.

Comment: I see now wot ur tying to do ... Maybe it is working but angular is not updating the view ... Consider using scope.apply

Comment: Unfortunatelly it doesn't

Comment: yes it does provide an answer. it might be the wrong answer but it sure is an answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was wrong. The problem is that the variable I pass is primitive. The solution is to change my variables to from primitive to objects.

So in my case the solution is:

```
base.myVar = {
    val: "string_1"
};

function myFunction(value) {
    value.val = "string_2";
};
```